# commend Get-WindowsFeature in Power Shell 5?

Tags: powershell

When i type the command `Get-WindowsFeature` in PowerShell 5 it displays this error, and I don't know why!

```
Get-WindowsFeature: The term "Get-WindowsFeature" is not recognized as a cmdlet name,
function, script file or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
access exists, verify that the path is correct and try again.
To the character Line: 1: 1
+ Get-WindowsFeature
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (Get-WindowsFeature: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Get-WindowsFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj205469(v=wps.630).aspx) is not part of PowerShell 5, but of the `Server Manager` module, which is either not installed or loaded, because the error message clearly states, that the command you trying to execute is not available.

Use `Import-Module ServerManager` to import it, or `Import-Module -ListAvailable` to see if it's even installed.

Comment: thank you Mr but how to download windows-feature to import after                        Import-Module ServerManager  XXX ,   I put what after server manager (xxx) ?

Comment: Not sure, but it might be part of [RSAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems). If not, you'll have to use a server OS.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you not trying to access Get-ImportModule through Powershell(x86). It's not there. Use the regular Powershell and you will be fine.